# Class Loader Exception while working with Maps in android

Tags: android

**I got the following Class not found exception while working with map based application**

```
 09-26 15:33:19.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27866):
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
 ComponentInfo{com.zyksatwo/com.zyksatwo.MapRouteActivity}:
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zyksatwo.MapRouteActivity in
 loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.zyksatwo-1.apk]
 09-26 15:33:19.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27866): at
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1618)
 09-26 15:33:19.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27866): at
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1716)
 09-26 15:33:19.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27866): at
 android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124) 09-26
 15:33:19.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27866): at
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
 09-26 15:33:19.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27866): at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 09-26
 15:33:19.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27866): at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 09-26 15:33:19.810:
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27866): at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806) 09-26
 15:33:19.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27866): at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-26
 15:33:19.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27866): at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 09-26 15:33:19.810:
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27866): at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 09-26 15:33:19.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27866): at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 09-26
 15:33:19.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27866): at
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-26 15:33:19.810:
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27866): Caused by:
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zyksatwo.MapRouteActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.zyksatwo-1.apk
```

Please help me to figure out the mistake I did here

Comment: did you add **<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"
  />** in your menifest file

Comment: if you are testing in emulator then are you sure that you are using Google-API for Map in emulator?

Comment: @CapDroid above tag i kept outside application tag, if i keep inside works fine thank you..

Comment: thats goood and i given you answer check it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you add `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` in your menifest file?

if not then plz add this Tag inside your `Application` Tag in your `Menifest.xml` file