# grpc failed while working with maps and location

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, grpc-java

> I am working with Maps and Location,the following code is right but then also it shows **`grpc failed`**

```
Geocoder gc=new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> list=gc.getFromLocationName("White House",1);
        Address adr=list.get(0);
```

How can i resolve it?
i am using **android studio 2.3.3.**

Comment: [use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553657/class-loader-exception-while-working-with-maps-in-android)

Comment: What was the solution? I get the same error. I'm not using maps, just Geocoder. I tried adding <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> to the manifest just in case, but didn't solve anything.

Comment: Anybody knows the answer??? i started getting this just today, its been working all along and suddenly it stopped working just now and throwing exception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.io.IOException: grpc failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012289/java-io-ioexception-grpc-failed)

Comment: Anybody knows any solution, I also started to get this error. Frustrating thing is that, It works on some real device but on some not. And have tried almost all possible solutions, but no result.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been addressed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256093/20394

Solution is to upgrade Google Play services to revision 44+

Comment: Instead of posting the link to the post, flag the question as duplicate

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, I was in a Fragment and my solution was creating the Geocoder sending `new Geocoder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());` instead `new Geocoder(getContext());`

I hope it help you

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by reducing the work in main thread. I tried to restart the emulator and reinstall android studio but nothing works.Then, I noticed some messages in logcat

> "Skipped 305 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on
>   its main thread."

I thought my app was having a heavy work so I moved all google map's location method to background thread and now it works like a charm. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I used to get same error. I solved it by creating the `Geocoder` in the following way:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue by adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

to my manifest file.

Turning wifi off and on at the start of the application was solving the error but this made it so I didnt have to do that every time.